# UnsatisfiedLinkError в OpenCV

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, opencv

Всем привет !

Появился вопрос, касательно библиотеки `OpenCV`. Подключил я ее по [этой](http://sumitkumariit.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-install-opencv-for-java-on-mac.html) инструкции. **Классы** из **библиотеки** видит без проблем, но вот в этом участке кода:

```
public static Mat cargar(String image, boolean gr, boolean bw, int thr) throws IOException {

        Mat imagen = Imgcodecs.imread("/Users/***/Desktop/"+image);

        if (gr)
            Imgproc.cvtColor(imagen, imagen, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        if (bw)
            Imgproc.threshold(imagen, imagen, thr, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
        return imagen;
    }
```

ругается:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J  at
>   org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Native Method)    at
>   org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread(Imgcodecs.java:102)     at
>   Functiones.cargar(Functiones.java:24)     at Main.main(Main.java:14)

С этой ошибкой встретился впервые, почитал на разных ресурсах, у многих решилось это тем, что они дописали

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

и все заработало. У меня же нет.

Я так понимаю, он просто не видит этой библиотеки ? Но если бы не видел, то оно бы показало, что такой библиотеки просто напросто не существует, у меня же во время компиляции только **Exception** .

После того, как добавляю строку `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);`, то уже другой **exception:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   opencv_java310 in java.library.path   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)  at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)    at
>   Functiones.cargar(Functiones.java:24)     at Main.main(Main.java:14)

Я не правильно что то подключил ? Но делал все по инструкции (сверху ссылка).

**OC:** *Mac OS El Capitan (10.11.4 (15E65))*
**Среда разработки:** *Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)*

Спасибо !

Comment: Там на сайте имеется [ссылка на en.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192866/executable-jar-with-opencv-lib-eclipse-mac) с ответом на похожий вопрос. Пробовали делать то, что там описано?

Comment: @alexis031182 только что попробовал: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /Users/****/Documents/workspace/OpenCVlibopencv_calib3d.3.1.0.dylib

Comment: Проверьте, может этого файла `OpenCVlibopencv_calib3d.3.1.0.dylib` нет по указанному пути. `Calib3d` - это отдельный модуль в OpenCV. По идее, он не должен грузиться Вашей программой, поскольку вовсе не используется в коде примера. Впрочем, на java могут быть свои особенности, а я к сожалению не знаток.

Comment: @alexis031182 существует =( второй день не могу понять что Eclipse хочет от меня.

Comment: Подумал, что может быть стоит попробовать отключить "calib3d" ещё на этапе сборки OpenCV. Добавьте флаг `-D BUILD_opencv_calib3d=OFF` к команде `cmake`. Если будет ругаться ещё на какой модуль, то точно также его в расход. Понятно, что это не фонтан, но хотя бы можно будет получить рабочий базис, чтобы потом уже иметь возможность разбираться с каждым модулем в отдельности и по необходимости.